# Rails Many to Many with condition adding new condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am modelling users and movies with "liked" and "recommeded".

The models are as follows:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :imbd_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :liked_by, :class_name => "User", 
    :conditions => { "type" => "like" }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recommended_by, :class_name => "User", 
    :conditions => { "type" => "recommend" }

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies_liked, :class_name => "Movie", 
    :conditions => { "type" => "like" }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies_recommended, :class_name => "Movie", 
    :conditions => { "type" => "recommend" }

end
```

with one table to map the relationship:

```
 create_table "movies_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "movie_id"
    t.string   "type"           # this can be "like" or "recommend"
    t.string   "status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Now I am getting an error when I try to do

```
u = User.first
m = Movie.first
u.movie_liked << m
```

with the following error

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > u.movies_tweeted << m 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: movies.type: SELECT * FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "movies_users" ON "movies".id = "movies_users".movie_id WHERE ("movies_users".user_id = 1  AND ("movies"."type" = 'like'))
```

Any idea I can structure it nicely so I can just use the << operator and it will automatically assign the correct type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Recommendation` and `Like` models and use them to join the Users with Movies. Or just a single model called don't know how(`RecommendLike`?), if you really wish to save on one table. And then:

```
User
  has_many :recommendations
  has_many :movies_recommended, :class_name => "Movie", :through => :recommendations
  has_many :likes
  has_many :movies_liked, :class_name => "Movie", :through => :likes
```

Comment: But then how do I add a relationship between a User and a Movie with a specific type then? ( I am specifically referring to how I could populate movies_users)

Comment: My suggestion is a replacement for your table `movies_users` as you can't have any extra attributes in join-tables used in `has_and_belongs_to_many`. There are actually different approaches in this case. You can have `recommended_movies_users` and `liked_movies_users` if you insist on using `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: I would always prefer to have less tables. your approach creates 2 additional models which I find to be a bit overkill

Comment: I wouldn't save on tables if it makes the code cleaner. But anyway, you can't get away with the existing tables. At least, you have to create one extra table.

Comment: So let say I decided to go with RecommendLike and then have an extra column called type (like||recommend). I guess in users it will be has_many :recommendlikes; has_many :movie_recommended, :class_name => "Movie", :through => :recommendlikes, :conditions => { "type" => "recommend" }? and then to save this relationship, I should just create a new Recommendlike and then populate the attribute and save?

Comment: Yes. But your existing `movies_users` won't be needed anymore. And don't call the column `type`, it's a reserved name for single table inheritance.

Comment: Oh. I think it should be `has_many :recommendations, :class_name => 'RecommendLike', :conditions => { "type" => "recommend" }`; `has_many :movie_recommended, :class_name => "Movie", :through => :recommendations`. Sorry, missed this.